# Getting the RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists) with a multi-input Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I'm unable to save a Keras model as I get the error mentioned in the title. I have been using tensorflow-gpu. My model consists of 4 inputs each is a ResNet50. When I use only a single input the call back below worked perfectly, but with the multi inputs I'm getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists)

```
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30,mode='min', min_delta=0.0001, verbose=1),
    ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, monitor='val_loss',save_best_only=True, mode='min', verbose=1)
]
```

Now without the callback I couldn't save the model at the end of training as I got the same error, but I was able to fix that using this code [found here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27688#issuecomment-504077960):

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

with K.name_scope(model.optimizer.__class__.__name__):
    for i, var in enumerate(model.optimizer.weights):
        name = 'variable{}'.format(i)
        model.optimizer.weights[i] = tf.Variable(var, name=name)
```

This code only works with single input model and put after the training function `model.fit`.

With the callbacks even the above code is not working. This post is somehow related to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105553/getting-an-error-with-a-multi-input-keras).

I have read that this issue can be fixed with `tf-nightly`  so I tried that, but didn't work.

I have tested with a [standalone code and generated data in a Google colab and it worked](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_yqIkVU4H9b8k-sMPGf-FjH7Dzy6s7PO?usp=sharing). So I checked the tf version, it's the same as mine `2.3.0`. As for cuda, both colab and my machine is running with :

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Could this be the issue?

**Update:**

Here the output error :

```
113/113 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 30.0107 - mae: 1.3525
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.18677, saving model to saved_models/multi_channel_model.h5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fine_tuning.py", line 111, in <module>
    run()
  File "fine_tuning.py", line 104, in run
    model.fit(x=train_x_list, y=train_y, validation_split=0.2,
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1137, in fit
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 412, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 1249, in on_epoch_end
    self._save_model(epoch=epoch, logs=logs)
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 1301, in _save_model
    self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True, options=self._options)
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1978, in save
    save.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 130, in save_model
    hdf5_format.save_model_to_hdf5(
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 125, in save_model_to_hdf5
    save_optimizer_weights_to_hdf5_group(f, model.optimizer)
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 593, in save_optimizer_weights_to_hdf5_group
    param_dset = weights_group.create_dataset(
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 139, in create_dataset
    self[name] = dset
  File "/home/abderrezzaq/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 373, in __setitem__
    h5o.link(obj.id, self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl, lapl=self._lapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5o.pyx", line 202, in h5py.h5o.link
RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with duplicate variable names leading to a `RuntimeError` when using several instances of pre-trained models and saving them to `h5` by modifying a protected attribute. This is not recommended in general, but in my case, I needed a solution *now*, and was not concerned with future proofing. I am working with `tensorflow-gpu 2.3.0` on `CUDA 10.1`.

I put the following before compilation, after creating the combined model `my_model`. Training and saving checkpoints worked as expected.

Edit: Note that in my case, upon loading the `h5` file of the combined model, the same steps will have to be performed if you want to save again.

```
    for i, w in enumerate(my_model.weights):
        split_name = w.name.split('/')
        new_name = split_name[0] + '_' + str(i) + '/' + split_name[1] + '_' + str(i)
        my_model.weights[i]._handle_name = new_name
```

Modifying the `optimizer.weights` of the combined model, as in the suggestion you mentioned, did not help in my case. I also opted to load the pre-trained models with `load_model(compile=False)` to remove their optimizer weights.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63785845/4046657) is another discussion I found about this, with a similar "solution" in the comments.

Comment: I will definitely try it and come back to you if it works for me.

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but it does not save the best only, it saves all the bests?

Comment: nice that it worked! If I understand the issue correctly, you have a lot of "best weight" `.h5` files. The best weights are saved incrementally, i.e. every time the loss reaches a new minimum, a checkpoint is saved. The one relevant for you is the last one before training terminates. This is expected behavior of the `best_only` option of the `ModelCheckpoint`.

Comment: Yes, in the ModelCheckpoint I have  `save_best_only=True`.

Comment: Is your code now working as expected? I am not quite sure if this would be a separate issue. If my answer solved your problem, I would appreciate you marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Try with CUDA 10.1.
   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu says "TensorFlow supports CUDA® 10.1"
2. Something is wrong with `ModelCheckpoint` callback. Check checkpoint_path location Is it writeable? Also the reference says "*if save_best_only=True, the latest best model according to the quantity monitored will not be overwritten.*" So you may want to delete the last saver model or provide new unique name in checkpoint_path every time you run model. Most likely it prevents overwriting the previous model and throws error.

Comment: take compatibility recommendations seriously. With CUDA 11 + TF 2.3 0. you are in a risky territory.

Comment: I have installed the cuda 10.1. `nvidia-smi` gives `CUDA Version: 11.1` and  `nvcc --version` gives `Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243` I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It appears that the version showed by `nvidia-smi` is not the one installed. Now I'm sure that `cuda-10.1` is installed with tensorflow `2.3.0`. I run my code and it seems that the `modelcheckpoint` is not working and gives `RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists)`

Comment: something is wrong with `ModelCheckpoint` callback. Check `checkpoint_path` location Is it writeable?

Also [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) says  "if save_best_only=True, the latest best model according to the quantity monitored will not be overwritten." So you may want to delete the last saver model or provide new unique name in `checkpoint_path` every time you run model.

Comment: In the model name there is `_{epoch:02d}` which is different at each epoch. The problem is related to the weights variable names   `packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 593, in save_optimizer_weights_to_hdf5_group` that why it didn't occur with single inputs. The thing is that in the collab, it's working.

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187054/runtimeerror-unable-to-create-link-name-already-exists-when-i-append-hdf5-fil; and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169315/runtimeerror-unable-to-create-link-name-already-exists-keras

Comment: Tried the first one, it didn't solve the prblm. The second one, as my inputs are pretrained models I can't initialize their weights. That why I'm using the code in the post to rename the variables name of the weights but it seems only working after the training is done which prevents me to use the callback (ModelCheckPoint).

Comment: I use the same callback with the single output model and the multiple input one. With the single input, it works perfectly, no issue. With the multi input (N-input, each one is  pretrained model without its top layers) it crashes.